# I have installed bs4 in PyCharm and i still get an "is not defined" error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using PyCharm. I have installed `bs4` and still when i write this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

i get an `name 'BeutifulSoup' is not defined`error. I have seen many "solutions" but nothing helped.

Comment: I am not sure if the error is related to bad spelling in your code or whether you just mistype it when you were posting question, but be sure to double check.

Comment: I a sorry for the confusion i ment ''name 'BeautifulSoup' is not defined". This is not the error.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? Could you double check whether you have installed the bs4 package in the right environment (3.5 or 2.7) ?

Comment: sometimes you need to **restart pycharm** after installing packages. I normally avoid installing via pycharm, I use `pip` or `conda` on the **correct environment**.

Comment: @PedroLobito thnks mate. That was it.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you solved the problem. GL

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm packages can sometimes be very buggy, therefore try restarting PyCharm and your computer.

It's much easier if you just use **pip install**  .
Also check for the environment you're installing your Python Packages.